# Translate dynamic variable in twig

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

How do I translate this in twig? I have this variable in twig that is an array:

```php
$array = [
  ['number' => 7, 'name' => 'foo'],
  ['number' => 8, 'name' => 'bar'],
  ['number' => 10, 'name' => 'baz'],
  // ... and so on and so forth
]
```

Would like it to be something like this:

> The variables are 7 times for foo, 8 times for bar, and 10 times for baz.

Or

> The variables are 7 times for foo and 10 times for baz.

Or

> The variable is 7 times for foo.

Tried with something like this:

```
    {% set last = array|last %}
    {% set array = array|slice(0, array.length - 1) %}

    {% trans %}
      <p>The variables are
        {% for i in array %}
          {{ i.number }} times {{ i.name }},
        {% endfor %}
        , and {{ last.number }} number of {{ last.name }}
      .</p>
    {% endtrans %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful if you add the output of what you're actually seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
The variables are
{% for item in array %}
    {% if array|length > 1 and loop.last %}
        and 
    {% endif %}
    {{ item.number }} times for {{ item.name }}{% if loop.last %}.{% elseif array|length > 2 %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```